# How to activate and deactivate Windows 10 lock screen spotlight hints?

Tags: windows-10, windows-spotlight

On my Windows 10 lock screen spotlight I have hints/links which, when clicked, take me to a bing.com page upon login showing where the place on the picture is.

[image: https://img42.com/bA6lo]

How can I activate and deactivate these links?  I need to know because they are not visible on all computers in the network.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. What research have you done or what have you tried to resolve this on your own? What does being "*visible on all computers in the network*" have to do with the question? Removed the [spotlight] tag as it was not related to your question.

Comment: Means I work in an office and colleagues do not have these links on their lockscreens.

Comment: Is this in a domain environment? Is your computer on the same domain the other person's computer is?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1406686/keep-windows-10-lock-screen-spotlight-pictures-but-turn-off-all-texts-hints-ball, https://superuser.com/questions/1254866/is-there-a-way-to-remove-ads-from-windows-spotlight, https://superuser.com/questions/1330900/why-is-my-windows-lock-screen-spamming-me, https://superuser.com/questions/1327459/remove-fun-facts-from-spotlight-lock-screen-in-windows-10-home-1803

Answer (score 6):

Once tips are enabled as described in the answer by [charlierb](https://superuser.com/users/97028/charlierb), it may happen that they are not shown nonetheless.

A possible reason is that they are disabled by a User Accounts setting.

- At a command prompt, type `Control Userpasswords2`
- In the User Accounts form, go to the *Advanced* tab
- Clear the *Require users to press Ctrl+Alt+Delete* option and click `OK`

Now check if tips are shown, by typing `WINDOWS+L` to go to the Lock Screen.

Answer (score 6):

Andrea's post is 100% the right answer to the OP's question for how to enable the feature.  CharlieRB referenced a post for how to disable the feature, but it does no good in enabling it for the people who are in the position to be searching for this solution (such as myself).

It turns out that on an Active Directory workstations, if you have “Require users to press Ctrl+Alt+Del” on the old “User Accounts” dialog, under the “Advanced” tab, it withholds the capability for the user to show ANY additional data on the Lock Screen.  Presumably this is meant to keep the user from leaking information via showing their Calendar events, Emails previews, etc..  But this has the added effect of keeping the user from being allowed to enable the above requested feature for showing additional information about the day's current lock screen background.

**Solution to Enable on Domain Computers**

1. Go to “Start” → “Run”
   or hit <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open the “Run” dialog box
   (or just go into a “Command Prompt” window).
2. Type: `control userpasswords2` to open the "User Accounts" dialog windows.
3. Go to the “Advanced” tab.
4. Under “Secure sign-in”,
   uncheck the “Require users to press Ctrl+Alt+Del” option box.
5. Hit “OK”.
6. Now simply make sure you have “Windows Spotlight” chosen in the “Personalization” → “Lock Screen” window and lock your workstation to see it working!

Comment: Now I'm being downvoted for posting the right answer? CharlieRB's post doesn't help with the actual problem being expressed in the question, how to disable is the obvious part, it's how to enable that's hidden. PS- Thanks Scott for the snazzy formatting fixes.

Answer (score 5):

To enable or diasble this feature, follow these steps;

1. Go to Settings.
2. Choose the `Personalization` setting.
3. Select the `Lockscreen` tab.
4. Under `Picture`, either choose `Windows Spotlight` to enable, or
   another choice to disable `Windows Spotlight.
5. Also, you can choose to enable or disable the `Get fun facts, tips,
   tricks, and more on your lock screen` toggle.

[Source](http://www.howtogeek.com/243263/how-to-disable-ads-on-your-windows-10-lock-screen/)

Comment: How do I enable the toggle button? Screenshot with it missing is at https://img42.com/vFUum

Comment: I think that is part of Spotlight. Does it appear if you turn off Windows Spotlight?

Comment: If I switch to `Picture` background I see the `Get fun facts, tips,
tricks` toggle button. It is currently on and I did not immediately see links. Will wait for tomorrow. Anyway my colleagues that does not have the links does not have the button even when background is set to `Picture`

Comment: No, this approach does not work.

Comment: Can you be more specific? This answers to your original question about how to enable or disable the feature. If there is another problem with it not working as you expect, you should have asked that question.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The toggle is simply missing. When I select Picture, the toggle appears, I turn it Off, then return the mode back to Windows Spotlight and ads are still shown on lock screen.