# Is there a way to remove ads from Windows spotlight?

Tags: windows-10

I like the Windows spotlight feature that rotates different background images in the lock screen. However, it has recently started showing random annoying text ads.

[image: ads in spotlight]

Is there a way to get rid of these ads *without disabling Windows spotlight*?

I'm using Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove "fun" facts from Spotlight lock screen in Windows 10 Home (1803)](https://superuser.com/questions/1327459/remove-fun-facts-from-spotlight-lock-screen-in-windows-10-home-1803)

Answer (score 8):

There are two ways:

- [by enabling Secure Sign-in](https://mywindowshub.com/how-to-enable-or-disable-secure-sign-in-with-ctrlaltdelete-in-windows-10/). You get to keep your Spotlight rotation wallpapers but all the text ads get replaced with a single "Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to unlock" just above the clock. This worked for me today.
- by installing Dynamic Theme from the MS Store and configure it to Spotlight Wallpaper. This worked at least up to a month ago.

Other solutions you may come across are outdated and patched and will not work now, or they require you to not use Spotlight. Namely,

- Turning off 'Get fun facts, tips and more from Windows and Cortana on your lockscreen'. This option has been patched to only show up if you select Picture mode or Slideshow mode, neither of which allows you to keep Spotlight mode.
- Turning off the above option in Picture/Slideshow mode and then switching back to Spotlight. This doesn't work because the option simply isn't relevant to Spotlight anymore, the setting will not persist when you switch back to Spotlight.
- Editing your Local Group Policy under Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Cloud Content > Do not show Windows Tips. This has been patched to not apply to the text ads on Spotlight.

Comment: In your second bullet, are you saying when you set 'Background' in the Daily Picture app to 'Windows Spotlight' you get just the current widows spotlight image only (no ads) and not the standard windows spotlight offering with ads? I thought that setting was just standard windows spotlight (with ads). There's another option for 'One Windows Spotlight Image' but I believe this is random, not the one current image. I could be wrong about that. This is how the Daily Picture settings page looks to me on 07/02/2021 in windows version 1909 : https://postimg.cc/ZCFC012X

Comment: Can confirm that the `Dynamic Theme` solution (setting it to Spotlight wallpaper) still works, at least in Windows 10. Now I still get the nice spotlight lock screen images, but none of the ads/suggestions. I even still get the image description (optional). It's a brilliant solution!

Answer (score 3):

Run `regedit` and navigate to

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ContentDeliveryManager
```

(you can paste that)

Then change value `SubscribedContent-338387Enabled` to `0`.

Works with Windows 10 2004

Comment: It seems to just preform switch off window spotlight feature.

Answer (score -3):

settings, personalization, lock screen, turn off "get fun facts...from cortana on your lock screen"

Comment: I don't see that on my instance. It might be super useful to add a screenshot of this specific settings page.

Comment: This option has been removed as of winver 1803. Not sure in which update though.

Answer (score -4):

Just to add to this - Go to 
Settings > Personalisation > Lock screen >

Under 'Background' select: 'Picture'.

Turn off: 'Get fun facts, tips and more from Windows and Cortana on your lockscreen'.

The only way to see that setting above is to have 'Picture' selected. 
You can then change the Background back to Slideshow or Windows Spotlight if you choose.

Comment: question asks about removing text without changing from spotlight.