# Remove "fun" facts from Spotlight lock screen in Windows 10 Home (1803)

Tags: windows-10, spotlight, windows-10-v1803, windows-spotlight

UPDATE: I tried all solution proposed in [How to disable “link your phone” links on the lock screen?](https://superuser.com/questions/1325947/how-to-disable-link-your-phone-links-on-the-lock-screen) and none of them seem to work on  Windows 10 Home (version 1803), so this is probably not a duplicate question.

I like Spotlight on my lock screen, it keeps things fresh :). And with the 1803 update, I get new images more frequently, which is good. But with that same update some new "fun" facts were added, which mess up the picture.[image]

Can I remove these facts ?

In the lock screen settings for Spotlight, there is no option to remove these:

[image]

I even switched to the lock screen picture settings to deactivate the setting, but that doesn't help either:

[image]

I already searched the internet, and some say to use the Group Policy settings, but they are not available on windows 10 Home edition.

Can this be done, or do I have to live with the "fun" facts ?

Update: I installed the Group Policy Editor and enabled the suggested option:

[image]

But I still have the facts displayed on my lock screen, even after a reboot.

Comment: Great question. Today I had **"_For obvious reasons_ this body of water is known as Mirror Lake _because of the reflective quality of its surface_"**  Neither end of that sentence needs to be present, and certainly not both (if something is "obvious", you don't need to explain it.  If these "fun facts" did not talk to you like you were a 5 year old they'd be less annoying.  Planting text in the middle of a beautiful image is also really dumb.

Answer (score 52):

It appears that at some point in the last year or two, the "Get fun facts" checkbox is no longer honored when you switch back to the Windows Spotlight option.

I have two Windows 10 machines, both build 1803. Both are set to use Windows Spotlight on the lock screen, but the older one does not show the tips and advertisements while the new one does.  This was driving me crazy so I decided to dig into it, and I found this question while looking for an answer.

There are some non-GPO registry settings related to "subscribed content" in Windows 10 and one of these appears to control the lock screen tips.  Under the key:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ContentDeliveryManager`

Set the DWORD value `ContentDeliveryAllowed` to `1`.
Set the DWORD value `RotatingLockScreenEnabled` to `1`.
Set the DWORD value `RotatingLockScreenOverlayEnabled` to `0`.
Set the DWORD value `SubscribedContent-338387Enabled` to `0`.

Why this works:

`ContentDeliveryAllowed` must be enabled for any of the dynamic content to work and should be enabled by default unless you've turned it off with policy. 
`RotatingLockScreenEnabled` enables the dynamic background picture instead of a static one. `RotatingLockScreenOverlayEnabled` is the "Get fun facts" option in the Settings app and setting it to 0 disables it.

Each of the `SubscribedContent` values appears to control a different part of the Windows UI, such as the start menu, taskbar, notifications area, etc., and `338387` seems to be the one for showing tips on the lock screen.

Comment: These days there are keys `SubscribedContent-338388Enabled` and `SubscribedContent-338389Enabled`.

Comment: @Phrogz and what do either of those represent?

Comment: SubscribedContent-338387Enabled is still the one to use. You have to create the key yourself.

Comment: My (relatively) new Windows 10 install had 33837, 8, 9 keys all set to 1. It had `RotatingLockScreenOverlayEnabled` set to `0` but still showed the fun facts. With value `...7` also set to `0`, no fun facts appear.

Comment: BTW this is Win10 Enterprise 21H1 (19043.985) 64-bit.

Comment: Do these changes require a reboot?

Comment: This hack worked for windows 11 (home) too!

Comment: This removes "Like what you see?" : or the option to switch to a new picture.

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 10 without reboot

Comment: Works for Win11 22H2. Should be accepted answer.

Comment: Works for Win10 Pro 22H2. Thank you!

Comment: Works on 22H2 19045.2604. I had to create 338387 key. Is there a way to keep "Like what you see" but disable other tips?

Answer (score 4):

The only way that seems to consistently remove the ads but continue to rotate the spotlight pictures is to enable secure sign-in, which forces you to press ctrl+alt+del to get to the sign-in screen.

It is annoying to require extra keystrokes to sign-in, but it's worth it to get rid of the ads.

To enable secure sign-in, open the group policy editor via `gpedit.msc`, and look for:

Local Computer Policy | Computer Configuration | Windows Settings | Security Settings |
Local Policies | Security Options | Interactive Login: Do not require CTRL+ALT+DEL

Set its value to **Disabled**.  Then reboot.

Answer (score 4):

The existing answers didn't work for me. I'm using 21H1 build 19043.1110.

I have disabled the overlay by changing the security settings of the folder that stores the metadata for the lockscreen.

```
%localAppData%\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\TargetedContentCache\v3\338387
```

Right click the folder to open the properties, the go to the security tab and click Advanced. The click Add, select principal the user "Everyone", select type Disallow, and check only the "Write" permission. Then select OK in each window.

Comment: I gave this a go, and so far, so good. I just nuked everything in the folder and marked it readonly.

Comment: I tried this fix and also the registry editor fix.  Each seemed to work at first, but then the next day it did not provide new images.  It just gave me default windows blue shape pictures.  So far I haven't found a fix that works.

Answer (score 1):

I simultaneously open Windows Settings and the Registry Editor, so that I can see how changes in the Settings are reflected in the registry. <sup>1</sup>

1. <kbd>Win-key</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> > Personalization > Lock screen
2. <kbd>Win-key</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>, type `regedit`, press <kbd>OK</kbd>.
   Go to `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ContentDeliveryManager`.
3. To begin with, I set all the `DWORD` values `RotatingLockScreenEnabled`, `RotatingLockScreenOverlayEnabled`, and `SubscribedContent-338387Enabled` to `0`. <sup>2</sup>

In the Settings, I turn ON **Get fun facts, tips, and more […]**. 
Then the registry values `RotatingLockScreenOverlayEnabled` 
and `SubscribedContent-338387Enabled` both change from `0` to `1`. <sup>3</sup>

Under **Background**, when I change from **Picture** to **Windows spotlight**,
the registry value `RotatingLockScreenEnabled` then also goes from `0` to `1`.

As [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1360999) hints, I don't think it's possible to have Windows Spotlight ON, while at the same time having **Get fun facts** OFF.

But here is a registry trick: now set `RotatingLockScreenOverlayEnabled` and `SubscribedContent-338387Enabled` back to `0`.
The result is *almost* what the asker tries to do – the lock screen shows one of the spotlight images, while *not* displaying any "fun facts" on the lock screen.
The caveat is that the currently displayed spotlight image will never change – unless you force it to. <sup>4</sup>

Have a look in the Settings.
The **Lock screen** shows the spotlight image as **Picture**.
There is no way you can achieve this by just clicking any of **Windows spotlight** / **Picture** / **Slideshow**.

[image: The current spotlight image et as "Picture".]

##### About `ContentDeliveryAllowed`

I haven't figured out what `ContentDeliveryAllowed` does.
At one point, it seemed that setting `ContentDeliveryAllowed` to `0` would automatically launch Microsoft Edge on every logon, but I don't know why that would happen.
For now, I've set `ContentDeliveryAllowed` to `1`.

---

<sup>1</sup>
I am on Windows 10 Professional, 22H2.

<sup>2</sup>
If the `DWORD` value `SubscribedContent-338387Enabled` doesn't exist, [create it](https://superuser.com/q/1327459#comment2484848_1360999).
Right-click `ContentDeliveryManager` > `New` > `DWORD (32-bit) Value`, paste `SubscribedContent-338387Enabled`.
Set its value to `0`.
`SubscribedContent-338388Enabled` and `SubscribedContent-338389Enabled` do not seem to affect anything on the lock screen.

<sup>3</sup>
Press <kbd>F5</kbd> in the Registry Editor to see the changes.

<sup>4</sup>
To force a new image, in Settings > Personalization > Lock screen, change **Background** from **Picture** to **Windows spotlight**. Put the computer to sleep (<kbd>Win-key</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> > <kbd>u</kbd> > <kbd>s</kbd>) or hibernate (<kbd>Win-key</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> > <kbd>u</kbd> > <kbd>h</kbd>). 
On the lock screen, hover the camera icon, and click **Not a fan**.
The spotlight image will be switched.