# Remove fun facts etc from Windows 10 2004 Pro?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-v2004

[Remove "fun" facts from Spotlight lock screen in Windows 10 Home (1803)](https://superuser.com/questions/1327459/remove-fun-facts-from-spotlight-lock-screen-in-windows-10-home-1803)

Attempted the answer in here, however no longer works in 2004. I really like the changing lockscreen image, however don't like the tips etc that appear.

Anyone know how I can hide them via registery, gpedit etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 V2004 is different than V1803.

Click on Start, Settings, Personalization, Lock Screen and turn OFF "Get Fun  Facts..."

I turned this off on all my computers.

You may need to restart after the change.

[image]

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/zWvdnuT.png

This does not appear on my menu

Comment: That setting is on all my Windows 2004 machines. Maybe your upgrade to Windows 2004 did not go properly. From an admin command prompt, run dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth followed by SFC /SCANNOW then restart and test.

Comment: I know what the issue is.  Change your background from Windows Spotlight to Slide Show and then the option should appear.