# Why is my Windows lock screen spamming me?

Tags: windows-10, lock-screen, windows-10-v1803

I'm running the Windows 10 April 2018 Update with Cortana enabled. Suddenly this morning there is a small earth/globe icon on my lock screen with the words: "Watch. Play. Connect.". There is another one of these icons on the top left of my lock screen showing: "Check out the most intense plays of the hottest games.".

When I click either of these icons, it opens up my browser to mixer.com. I have never used this service, don't stream games and don't play online games.

I have not installed any software recently so am confused as to where this came from. I do have an Xbox One and a Windows Phone of which all are connected via the same Live account.

I have "Windows spotlight" set as my background but thought that only gives a you nice new background picture every day?

Any ideas where this spam is coming from?

Comment: [this was already asked a few days ago](https://superuser.com/q/1327459/174557)

Comment: No, not actually. That question is the answer to mine: where is the spam coming from? I did not even know it was from Spotlight. That question is about how to specifically tune Spotlight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Spotlight puts ads on the lock screen. See [How to Disable Ads on Your Windows 10 Lock Screen](https://www.howtogeek.com/243263/how-to-disable-ads-on-your-windows-10-lock-screen/) to get rid of them.

It's (sort-of) [documented](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/windows-spotlight):

> Windows Spotlight is an option for the lock screen background that displays different background images **and occasionally offers suggestions on the lock screen.**

If you have Windows 10 Pro, that page shows how to disable  third-party content in Windows spotlight via Group Policy.

Comment: I rather like Spotlight giving me a new background image daily so don't really want to switch it off. Seems like that is the only affective way though as per the HowToGeeks article. I do have Win 10 Pro and have enabled the Group Policy on my machine but am still getting the adds on my lock screen. Is there something more I need to do to apply the group policy?

Comment: My computer is only part of a workgroup and not AD or a proper networked domain. Will group policies still work in that instance?

Comment: Yes, they should do. Have you [restarted Windows](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/140170-disable-windows-10-spotlight-on-lock-screen-through-group-policy) since setting it?

Comment: It was the first thing I did after applying the group policy but it didn't seem to work hence my added question above. Eventually I just left everything as is and the adds have stopped showing up on my lock screen a day or two later. I can't say why though. Maybe the policy eventually took affect, who knows...